# Can you use scanf() to define a variable set with #define?

Tags: c++

If I initialize a variable using #define, can I then set its value using scanf()? i.e. does this work:

```
#define miscellaneous
printf("What value would you like to use for this example: ");
scanf("%g",&miscellaneous);
```

If I can't do it this way, is it even possible to set the value of a variable defined this way?

Comment: `#define miscellaneous` does not create/initialize a variable, so no, this approach will not work.

Comment: The `#define` doesn't declare a variable. It simply defines a 'token' that is used by the preprocessor. In your case, it is defined as an empty token, so your `scanf` line is a syntax error.

Comment: Your _preprocessor directive_ performs a text _search and replace_, replacing the text `miscellaneous` with an empty string before your compiler ever gets to see the code.  It is not a variable in any sense.  What your compiler sees is `scanf("%g",&);`, as you have defined the text `miscellaneous` to mean _nothing_.

Comment: If you want `miscellaneous` to be a macro, you'll need to *escape* the line ends (or add continuation characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define miscellaneous` means that every time you write `miscellaneous`, you would like the compiler to replace it with nothing. `#define` is automated copy-paste and in this case it pastes nothing.

So when you write `scanf("%g", &miscellaneous);` the macro (the `#define`) causes it to be changed to `scanf("%g", &);` which is not valid at all. This is not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

> If I can't do it this way, is it even possible to set the value of a variable defined this way?

`miscellaneous` is not a variable at all. What you have defined is a macro. And no, you cannot set the value of a macro at runtime. Macro processing happens before compilation which happens before the program is run.

P.S. Avoid unnecessary use of macros.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign value to `macro`. Using `#define directive` compiler only in compile time using it, in runtime everything defined using `#define directive` does not exist.